# subprocess.check_output failing within Docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, neo4j, subprocess

Similiar questions have been asked before, but the solutions for these questions don't resolve my own issue. I have a repo that relies on a base repo, whereby a connection is made to a neo4j database. My tests for the base repo work. The repo I have (transforms files) has already proven to work locally. When I run the repo in Docker I get a `FileNotFoundError` which is being thrown out from the base repo:

**Base repo module**

```
def get_docker_host_ip(self):
    z = subprocess.check_output(['ip', '-4', 'route', 'list', 'match', '0/0'])
    z = z.decode()[len('default via '):]
    return z[: z.find(' ')]
```

The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/app/src/myscript.py", line 252, in <module>
    myModule = My_Module(args)
  File "/opt/app/src/myscript.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.neo4jadapter = Neo4jAdapter()
  File "/opt/app/base/base/neo4j_adapter.py", line 19, in __init__
    neo4j_host = self.get_docker_host_ip()
  File "/opt/app/base/base/neo4j_adapter.py", line 51, in get_docker_host_ip
    z = subprocess.check_output(['ip', '-4', 'route', 'list', 'match', '0/0'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 472, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ip': 'ip'
```

For `subprocess.check_output`, I have also added `shell=True` as recommended on other posts, but it doesn't make a different:

```
z = subprocess.check_output(['ip', '-4', 'route', 'list', 'match', '0/0'], shell=True)
```

This Traceback only occurs when I run the script in Docker. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Docker containers often don't have low-level network-management tools like `ip`; Docker itself manages the network environment.

Comment: @DavidMaze: thanks for the indication, yes it seems you're right. In fact adding 'RUN apt-get install iproute2' resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DavidMaze's comment, the `ip` tool needs to be installed via Docker, for example:

```
RUN apt-get install iproute2
```